# R packages for string capitalization (to title case) that exclude certain fill-words such as articles in Portuguese or other non-English languages?

Tags: r, string, case-sensitive, capitalization, capitalize

I am aware that tools::toTitleCase(my_string) does this for the English language. But I have searched and couldn't find a Portuguese-specific package.

```
my_string <- "hello this is my string"
toTitleCase(my_string)
# "Hello this is My String"
```

Here's a sample of titles with the correct grammar rules applied in Portuguese:

"Contra o Militarismo, Sóror Mariana, a Freira Portuguesa", "A Morgadinha dos Canaviais – Crónica da Aldeia", "Mil e Seiscentas Léguas pelo Atlântico", "Oração aos Moços", "Reflexões sobre a Língua Portuguesa", "Voltareis, ó Cristo?", "Algumas Palavras a Respeito de Púcaros em Portugal", "A Propósito de Pasteur", "Viagem à Roda da Parvónia"

Comment: You could write your own or copy somebody else's attempt, such as https://gist.github.com/jjesusfilho/454192db8356eb9c486a02698338221a

Comment: Any chance of you providing a list of articles and non-capital words in Portuguese?

Comment: Sure! Here's a sample:

Comment: @Henry thank you very much! You put me on the right track. Now I can help build the solution. :)
I'm not sure how to close this question based on your answer though... This is my first question on StackOverflow. 

I also found an alternative in Python that attempts TitleCase and accepts a list of words as exceptions. This will do the trick though I must do it in Python. :)

https://pypi.org/project/titlecase/